# PayPal agreement approval doesn't show a price

Tags: ruby, paypal

I'm using PayPal through the REST API and I'm a bit confused with what I get.

To consume it i'm using the [PayPal-Ruby-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK)

I'm creating a Plan like this:

```
paypal_plan = PayPal::SDK::REST::DataTypes::Plan.new(
  name: 'foo',
  description: 'bar',
  type: 'FIXED', 
  payment_definitions: [
    {
      name: 'foo',
      type: 'REGULAR',
      frequency_interval: '1',
      frequency: 'MONTH',
      cycles: '12', 
      amount: {
        currency: 'EUR',
        value: '15'
      }
    }
  ],
  merchant_preferences: {
    cancel_url: 'http://foo.com/cancel',
    return_url: 'http://foo.com/return'
  }
)
paypal_plan.create
# Active the plan on PayPal
patch = {
  path: '/',
  value: {
    state: 'ACTIVE'
  },
  op: 'replace'
}
paypal_plan.update(patch)
```

Then I create an Agreement related to this Plan:

```
PayPal::SDK::REST::DataTypes::Agreement.new(
  name: 'foo', 
  description: 'bar', 
  start_date: (Time.now + 1.hour).utc.iso8601,
  payer: {
    payment_method: 'paypal'
  },
  plan: {
    id: PLAN_ID
  }
)
```

Everything seems to work but when I navigate to the approval url it give me a web page without any detail about the Plan I'm going to subscribe.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually just playing with Billing Agreements in the Express Checkout API and noticed the same thing there.  It seems that when working with billing agreements the PayPal checkout pages get simplified and show nothing but the billing agreement.  It leaves it up to you to display a nice review page that includes the whole order in your site or application.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense, the customer doesn't have much informations when he confirm the with it's PayPal account the billing. He really have to trust the website who is billing him...